# Programmatically Turn off Triggers/Validations/Workflow

Tags: trigger, workflow, validation-rule

I wanted to explore using a [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) class upon sandbox creation but ideally need to disable triggers, validation and workflow rules first. Is there a way to do this programmatically via apex?

I feel like it should be possible, especially as the [Salesforce Toolkit](https://sfswitch.herokuapp.com/) can but is it possible to with apex itself?

Comment: Tooling API maybe? I don't think callouts are supported though.

Comment: I am sure I have read on here there is a way of doing, maybe using https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi ?

Comment: I mean I don't think the `SandboxPostCopy` context supports callouts.

Comment: ah. nuts. Time to have a "play" I guess!

Comment: What if you had a Custom Setting that you could flag to disable all the triggers, validation rules, workflows, etc... ? Just set it as the first part of the sandboxpostcopy class. They would still be active, but wouldn't actually do anything.

Comment: That is an option but I was trying to find a way without having to edit existing code - being a bit idealistic :)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my prior [comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142101/progmatically-turn-off-triggers-validations-workflow#comment205619_142101).

You can use a Custom Setting that can be flagged to disable all the triggers, validation rules, workflows, etc...

Just set it as the first part of the SandboxPostCopy class. The triggers etc.. would still be active, but wouldn't actually do anything.

---

Summer `17 is introducing [native Metadata access in Apex](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_metadata.htm). It is currently [limited](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm) to Custom Metadata Types and Layouts. Changing a triggers active state could be another good use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can try if **`Switch`** from [Salesforce Toolkit](http://sftoolkit.co/) could be helpful

> Quickly and easily disable an Org's validation rules, workflows and Apex triggers.